# Foursquare API : Pass array of venue id to get response

Tags: php, foursquare

I am facing one problem. I have script which gets venue id from db and passes it to Foursqaure. From response, I am only saving phone no in db. But currently I have 400 records in db which is taking appx 95 seconds to execute. So I was thinking can I pass venues id array to API so that I will have only one request to api and will reduce execution? Currently I am sending 400 request that is causing high time. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can use Group Multiple Requests
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/multi/multi

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the Foursquare `/multi` endpoint to perform multiple API requests in a single request. Something like this:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/multi?requests=
  /venues/:ID-1,
  /venues/:ID-2,
  /venues/:ID-3,
  /venues/:ID-4,
  ...,
  /venues/:ID-N
```

This will return a JSON payload containing a `responses` array with responses for each of the Venue endpoints.